# What address type do DNS queries use?

Tags: networking, dns, tcp, udp

I was reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/14985/what-is-anycast-and-how-is-it-helpful)  thread and it was mentioned that DNS servers use anycast address. I have also heard that there is something called Unicast DNS as well.

So, my question is what type of addresses do DNS queries use? (Unicast/Broadcast/Multicast/Anycast)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: all forms, depending on the servers, services and topology.

Note that anycast and unicast addresses are the same. Think of anycast as an address that is in multiple sites at once. Your query will be sent only to the closest one (network wise) and there is no difference contacting one or the other.

Other forms of DNS use multicast for their queries (say [Avahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)) or [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)). When you resolve *hostX.local* in your network, your are most likely using multicast.

`nmblookup` and other componentes of [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) can use broadcast.

Your first query will be done based on the resolution system of your computer, then, in order to get the information, different types of addresses might be used, even simultaneously, to get you an answer.